# Nautilus - How permanently keep my column sorting preferences for my download directory? ( 18.04.02)

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

In previous releases Nautilus kept my column sorting preferences .
It is not the case anymore .

Comment: When do you lose the preferences, after a logout, after a reboot, during the session itself?

Comment: During the nautilus session : e.g. I have directory A open and sorted by date , then I open directory B in the same window &  tab, then I come back to directory A : it is  now sorted by name !

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed not anymore how it works. Nautilus currently remembers the preferences of the last changed window as defaults for a new window.

Nautilus used to remember a per-folder setting in (much) older versions. In the forked file manager, nemo, it still works that way.